# External assembler function for digital signal processor

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, signal-processing, texas-instruments

I need to create external function on TMS320C5515 Fixed-Point Digital Signal Processor around `BFXTR` command. I need to write some value directly into memory. I tried something like this:

```
.def _bfxtr

_bfxtr:
    PSH mmap(ST0_55)
    PSHBOTH XCDP
    MOV T0, AC0
    MOV T1, AC1
    BCC why, AC1 >= #0
why:
    MOV HI(AC0), *(#(metka + 1))
    NOP
    //here comes 512 NOP commands to supress conveyor
    ....
    NOP
    NOP
    B metka

metka:
    BFXTR #0x0, AC1, T2
    MOV T2, T0
    POPBOTH XCDP
    POP mmap(ST0_55)
    RET
```

But nothing changes memory value. What can I do about it?

Comment: For niche products like this, I suspect you'll get better answers at some TI forum or perhaps at https://electronics.stackexchange.com (where questions about DSP firmware are perfectly on-topic).

Comment: @Lundin, Thank you, I'll try that.